# Removing unicode bullet character

Tags: php, mysql, regex, unicode

I'm having an issue that i believe is related to unicode text.  When the user enters a string that has the unicode bullet character, mysql is not able to save that field (the rest of the update query works though).  Here's how i've been trying to deal with it.

`$str = "·         Close up the server";`

```
$str = preg_replace("\u2022", "&bull;", $str);
```

...however this is still not working.

Comment: Did you try `$str = preg_replace("·", "&bull;", $str);` ?

Comment: Did you try `$str = htmlentities($str)`?

Comment: Tell us about your database's collation/encoding.  Suggested reading: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Table encoding: cp1252 Western European (latin 1)
Collation: latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: htmlentities is replacing the bullet with "&middot;" which is not desireable.  @vladimir - I tried that but its not working for me.

Comment: have you tried using utf-8 in your database? bullet is not the only character that will not successfully add to the database.

Comment: Using a "Windows Codepage" this is not surprising.  http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So many things can go wrong here, because database, form submits and source code string literals are all involved. I'll assume you want to use UTF-8, because with any other typical encoding (CP1252, Latin1) you'll be screwed when you want to use `json_` or accept more than ~200 different characters.

The first thing to do is *remove* any kind of conversion etc code that was written with the intention of trying to fix encoding issues. Such as `utf8_encode`, `htmlentitites`, `*_replace`.. whatever.

---

Source encoding.

```
$str = "· Close up the server";
```

When writing the above, the PHP source file needs to be physically encoded in UTF-8. If you are on Windows, you must explicitly do or configure this. UTF-8 doesn't happen magically on Windows.

---

Form submits

When user submits a form, the payload will be in whatever encoding you declared the page to be. You can declare it like so:

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

But anyone can actually submit arbitrary bytes to your server, so you should validate the input is in UTF-8 before proceeding. `mb_check_encoding` is good.

---

Database

Since at this point your data is coming in as UTF-8, your input strings are in UTF-8. You must specify this after connecting to the database, by specifying a connection encoding.

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8"); //After making the connection, and before any queries
//or $mysqli->set_charset( "utf8");
```

This makes the database read your input in UTF-8, and encode its output in UTF-8. You would also want to set your columns/tables/databases to UTF-8 as well.

---

Unicode escape sequences `\uxxxx` or `\uhhhh\ullll` or `\Uxxxxxxxx` are not supported in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

`\u2022` is the `UTF-16` hex encoding for "Bullet". Not `UTF-8`.

You might also want to `SET NAMES 'UTF-8';` or change charset before you open your database.

Comment: @ficuscr I don't think a lack of understanding warrants a downvote. If the OP had no lack of understanding, he wouldn't have asked a question in the first place. When someone has a question, it is usually because they have a "lack of understanding". By that logic, we should downvote every question because they are asking for answers, which is demonstrating a "lack of understanding".

Comment: @SkeetsO'Reilly don't recall this at all.  Wonder if I was referring to another answer?  Thanks.