# Unable to remove bullet point ' • ' using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-entities

I am trying to read data from mysql which is having following data

```
<b>Network Security, Router / Firewall</b>

• We have a minimum, sophisticated firewalls which has been deployed at all external connections (Example: Internet)
```

When I am fetching and printing it using PHP and using `htmlentities()` like following
`echo $message=htmlentities($message);`
I am getting empty space without any text.However by using the following code:

```
$search = array(chr(145),chr(146),chr(147),chr(148),chr(151));
$replace = array("'","'",'"','"','-');
$message=str_replace($search, $replace, $message);
echo $message;
```

I am getting the following result:

```
Network Security, Router / Firewall � We have a minimum, sophisticated firewalls which has been deployed at all external connections (Example: Internet)
```

Please help me removing the unwanted �

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977057/removing-unicode-bullet-character

Comment: adding header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); is not helping me

Comment: Lets stop at the first problem. I'm unable to reproduce that string not being echoable, https://3v4l.org/V5nTb.

Comment: @3v4l.org/V5nTb if I use htmlentities() blank space is coming. I cant see any text that time

Comment: @srikantamondal Blank space where, please use the username with the `@` so notifications are sent.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your bullet in source text is actual bullet, it might be some Unicode character e.g.

● BLACK CIRCLE        *25CF*
⚫ MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE *26AB*

Run this code below, you can add more characters to find in $search array list and add value to replace in $replace array.

```
$message = "• We have a minimum, sophisticated firewalls which has been deployed at all external connections (Example: Internet)";

$search = array(chr(145),chr(146),chr(147),chr(148),chr(151), "•");

$replace = array("'","'",'"','"','-', "");
$message=str_replace($search, $replace, $message);
echo $message;
```